# C - convert scancode set 1 to ASCII

Tags: c++, c, keyboard, driver

As the title says, I am looking for a way to convert a scancode to ASCII. I am writing this for a PS/2 keyboard driver; it would be of great help if someone could explain how I could do this, or provide some example code as a pointer for me to get started. If this isn't possible in C, I can also use C++ or x86 assembly.

Thank you!

Comment: A lookup table usually works great.

Comment: Linux, Windows, or Other?

Comment: Check out www.blitzbasic.com/Community/posts.php?topic=96096 for sample code and pitfalls

Answer (score 1):

You do this via a keyboard mapping table. But this really doesn't belong at the keyboard driver layer, because the mapping is specific to the user's configured layout/language. Instead the driver should output some sort of standardized key codes (could be scancodes, or something more abstract and geometric like X/Xkb uses), an intermediate layer should convert those to key names, and some other (much higher!) layer should convert named key events to changes to text entry contents.